# Autoreplaced string

Tags: php

I have format codes in my page and there is one weird problem: when user post text and text contain **%%integer some_text%%** appear a problem -- text replaced as **% some_text%** instead of

```
<span class="spoiler">integer some_text</span>
```

What could it be and how is it treated?

Comment: Where are these format codes you speak of?  Post them here.

Comment: Please try here: http://sich.co/b/res/4377 (and please click SAGE before posting).

Comment: Could this be dictated by htmlspecialchars() function?

Comment: No I mean post your server side code.  PHP code.  On this site.